# drawing two plots in one plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two plots. The x-axis for both is same, however the y-axis is different. I would like to plot both plots in one plot in a way that they share the same x-axis. x-axis represents time for both graphs. Any suggestions how to do that instead of plotting each one alone. The following picture shows what I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `subplot` and delete the x-axis tick labels of the top one, for example:

```
  x=rand(1,100);

  subplot(2,1,1);
  plot(1./x);
  ylabel('Label 1')
  set(gca,'XTickLabel',[])

  subplot(2,1,2);
  plot(x)
  ylabel('Label 2')
  xlabel('x Label')
```

[image]

If you want the plots to be closer to one another you can use one of the FEX files such as `subplot_tight` etc (for example [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30884-controllable-tight-subplot) , or [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32078-image-matrix-shift/content/shift/subplot_tight.m))

Or you can just use `axes`...

Comment: than you so much. For the plot in the bottom, x-axis seems to be belonged only to the bottom.

Comment: that's what you wanted right? they both share the same x-axis values and tick positions, however, only the bottom plot shows them.